# XGBClassifier default parameters printed as None in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to use XGBClassifier in python notebook as:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

To see the value of default parameters used I did:

```
XGBClassifier()
```

It prints the following output with None being the default value of all parameters:

```
XGBClassifier(base_score=None, booster=None, colsample_bylevel=None,
          colsample_bynode=None, colsample_bytree=None,
          enable_categorical=False, gamma=None, gpu_id=None,
          importance_type=None, interaction_constraints=None,
          learning_rate=None, max_delta_step=None, max_depth=None,
          min_child_weight=None, missing=nan, monotone_constraints=None,
          n_estimators=100, n_jobs=None, num_parallel_tree=None,
          predictor=None, random_state=None, reg_alpha=None,
          reg_lambda=None, scale_pos_weight=None, subsample=None,
          tree_method=None, validate_parameters=None, verbosity=None)
```

Can someone please tell me why all these values are None?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat unfortunately, those **are** the default parameters *for the python class* ([source](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/af0cf88921f4d80a2a338e40f2620c9579afa100/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L486)). The real default hyperparameters are stored in the C++ code that the python wrapper calls on.

Comment: so there is no way to find out the default parameter values?

Comment: The documentation lists all the defaults. I'm not sure if there's a nice programmatic way.